# Error from Django clickjacking middleware: Form has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, forms, django-urls

I have a form that contains 3 fields :

```
class AjoutBanque(forms.Form):
    nom=forms.CharField()
    agence=forms.CharField()
    rib=forms.IntegerField()
```

My view :

```
def AjoutBanq(request):
    if request.user.is_active :
        form2=AjoutBanque(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            print("valid")
            clt= banque(nom=form2.cleaned_data.get('nom'),agence=form2.cleaned_data.get('agence'),rib=form2.cleaned_data.get('rib'))
            clt.save()
    return redirect('/banque/')
```

When submiting my form it raises the error :

> 'AjoutBanque' object has no attribute 'get'

Here is the traceback :

```
 Traceback:
   File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
     packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  131.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)

   File "C:\Users\users MGE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
  32\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
   32.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

       Exception Type: AttributeError at /addbanque
      Exception Value: 'AjoutBanque' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My URLS :

```
url(r'^banque',views.BanqueViews.as_view(), name='banque'), //url that contains the form
url(r'addbanque$',views.AjoutBanque, name='banqueajout')//url of submit button of the form.
```

I don't know where this error came from, do you have any idea?

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: i have just add it

Comment: is `banque` a model? could you maybe post more of the view?

Comment: The traceback suggests that your view is returning the form instead of an http response. Make sure that your view is the same as in your code, and fix the indentation.

Comment: @jsm1th yes banque is a model.

Comment: @Alasdair  it's the same view i have in my code. i'll check the indention but i guess if the problem is the indention django gives an error of indention.

Comment: @jsm1th what should i post more about my view

Comment: I can't see how that view would cause that traceback. Perhaps a different view is handling the request, or you have forgotten to save code or restart your server, so you are not running the code you think you are.

Comment: I checked all things you said. but everything is okey. me too i cant see where would the problem be

Comment: Now that you've added the urls, we can see that it's not just a different view that is handling the request, but a form that is handling it!

Comment: it was an error, because the the view and the form have similar names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is `AjoutBanq` and your form is `AjoutBanque`. In your URLs, you are using the form instead of the view. It should be:

```
url(r'addbanque$',views.AjoutBanq, name='banqueajout')//url of submit button of the form.
```

I suggest you rename the form to `AjoutBanqueForm` so that there's less chance of confusion.

Comment: this is what i just noticed Now. Thank You for your Time.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work:
    from django.http import HttpResponse

```
def AjoutBanq(request):
    if request.user.is_active :
        form2=AjoutBanque(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            print("valid")
            clt= banque(nom=form2.cleaned_data.get('nom'),agence=form2.cleaned_data.get('agence'),rib=form2.cleaned_data.get('rib'))
            clt.save()
            return redirect('/banque/')
    return HttpResponse('')
```

You have to return HttpResponse in your views, otherwise django middlewares (in this case `django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware` will throw an error.

Comment: i've just noticed the problem. @Alasdair have noticed it too. i'm so thankful for your time everyone